# Help finding $(fg)(-2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So I just need a confirmation really, as my friend and I don't agree on the answer.

Problem: let $f(x)= \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$ and $g(x)=log_3 (x+3)+1$

Find $fg(-2)$

$f(-2)\cdot g(-2)$

$-4/3\cdot 1= -4/3$

But my friend got 1. Don't you have to find $f(-2)$ and $g(-2)$ first and then perform the multiplication or what?

Comment: Please use formatting

Comment: I assume the question is asking for composition rather than multiplication.  That is, you want $f\circ g(-2)=f(g(-2))$  In any case, you need to clarify what is meant by $fg$.

Comment: Does $fg(-2)$ mean $f(-2)\times g(-2)$ or does it mean $f\circ g(-2) = f(g(-2))$?

Comment: Without the open circle, I would certainly assume it is multiplication...

Comment: true , because composition changes the answer, what is $fg$?

Comment: Well your friend is wrong in either case $f\circ g(-2)$ is undefined (1/0).  I can't think we anyone write $f(x)g(x)$ as $fg(x)$ but $f(-2)\times g(-2)$ does equal -4/3.

Comment: It has a () out side fg so I'm thinking should that be $f \circ g$?

Comment: $fg(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is not standard notation by any means.  My assumption is it is compostition.  But if it *is* multiplication, the op is correct.  I think miswritten composition is far more likely than miswritten multiplication IMO.

Comment: The OP really needs to clarify what is meant by $fg$.  I edited the post for formatting, but left the functional expression as it originally appeared.  As I said, in general I'd have assumed that composition was intended.

Comment: This question badly needs clarification as to what $(fg)(x)$ means.

Comment: In general is $"fg(x)"$ taken to mean $f\circ g(x) = f(g(x))$?  The thing that throws me is the parenthesis around fg so $(fg)(x)$ is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean $f \circ g(-2)$ ... which means you first find $g(-2)$ which is 1, and then find $f(1)$, which is  $\infty$ ... so I'm not really sure what method you are using but both the answers seem wrong

Comment: It's not a composition I just used • to imply multiplication because I don't like using x. But it's (Fg)(-2) which is f(-2) multiplied by g(-2) sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Okay ... cause that's some really confusing notation I've never seen before, but yes, then its f(-2) x g(-2) = -4/3 x 1 = -4/3, so ur right

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it's important, how you defined a multiplication of function. Normally, it's a composition of functions and it's $f(g(x))$, but it's impossible in this example, because $g(-2)=1$, but for $x=-1$ function $f$ hasn't any sense, so it's impossible. If you define (fg)(x) as $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ - you're right.